# Substitute values with uncertainties in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, uncertainty

I am trying to differentiate an equation for air change efficiency and substitute the values of volume flow as integers using sumpy. This works absolutely fine. But in the next step i would like to apply uncertainities to the volume flows I substitute. Hence I used uncertainties module to acheive this, but whenever I use "ufloat", the "sympy" variables do not compute the end value.

Below is a simplified example (without differentiation) of what I would like to acheive. Is there any alternative where i can use mathematical operations along with uncertainties. Or atleast able to differentiate an equation and apply uncertainties.

```
from sympy import *
from uncertainties import ufloat

x , y = symbols("x, y")

eqn = pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)

a = eqn.subs({x:2, y:2})

b = eqn.subs({x:ufloat(2, 1), y:2})

print("without uncertainties: {}".format(a))

print("with uncertainties: {}".format(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

SymPy has `AccumBounds` which works more or less like an uncertainty interval:

```
In [8]: eqn.subs({x: AccumBounds(1.9, 2.1), y:2})
Out[8]: <7.61, 8.41>
```